# RDLC exported to excel to show negative numbers in parentheses

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

I have an rdlc file with cells showing decimals.
How do I convert a negative number to have parenthesis?

I can't display it as a string, because when the report is exported it treats in as a string and throws an error that the number could not convert a string.

I've tried adding `#,0:c0` for the format property but this didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you converting the number into string - if ToString method isn't working, you can try CStr mehtod - CStr(Fields!YourField.Value)

Comment: can't use strings cause it's cause exporting problems with decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out, sorry to answer my own question.

if I use the following in the format property `#,0;(-#,0)` it works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try to not use the Format function in the `Expression` of your Placeholder, instead in the text box (or cell) properties, you can set the type and the format of it.

In the properties, there is a section called `Number` in which you specify that the textbox must contains numbers of a specificated category.

Here is an image to explain:
[image]

As you can see, there is an option to set how to display negative numbers (the one selected).

Now, I'm sure that this will works if you export the report in PDF but I hope this will be the same for Excel's export

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2008, so that option is not available. Thanks though.

Comment: Next time try to specifiy in the question the version of your visual studio. Glad to hear that you have resolve

Comment: Yeh, sorry, thanks though. i'll give you an up vote for helping out and it's the solution for 2010 I assume

Answer (score 0):

In my case below custom expression solved my problem.

`''#,0.00;''(#,0.00);`